# Como pegar o tempo de ping com o módulo https do nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Como posso realizar o cálculo do ping entre cliente e servidor usando o módulo http/https do node.

OBS: Uso esse modulo em especifico pois o objetivo do script é gerar log de disponibilidade deum site a cada meio minuto com o seguinte output:

```
200 | www.site.com | 350 ms | 19-08-2019 12:10:29
```

Fiquem a vontade para indicara algum módulo pronto para isso.

```
const https = require('https');
const hostname = 'www.site.com';

setInterval(()=>{
  const req = https.request({
    hostname: hostname
  }, function (res){
    console.log(`${res.statusCode} | ${hostname} | ${new Date().toISOString().slice(0,19).replace('T',' ')}`);
  });
  req.on('error',(e)=>{
    console.log('Erro: '+e);
  });
  req.end();
},3000);
```

Output atual:

```
200 | www.site.com | 19-08-2019 12:10:29
```

Tentei usar listenners para capturar o tempo atual no ato do ínicio da requisição e subtrari com o tempo no final da mesma, porém não achei o evento que é disparado nomomento em que o request é executado, e não sei se essa é a maneira correta para calcular o tempo do ping.

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso aqui -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737130/how-to-ping-from-a-node-js-app

Comment: Acredito que isto não seja válido para fazer log. Pois eu teria de fazer uma requisição para validar se o server http responde 200 e outra para validar o tempo do ping.

Answer (score 1):

Tente :

```js
const https = require('https');
const hostname = 'www.site.com';

setInterval(()=>{
  let startRequest  =  new Date().getTime();
  const req = https.request({
    hostname: hostname
  }, function (res){
 const pingTime =  new Date().getTime()- startRequest;
    console.log(`${res.statusCode} | ${hostname} | ${pingTime} | ${new Date().toISOString().slice(0,19).replace('T',' ')}`);
  });
  req.on('error',(e)=>{
    console.log('Erro: '+e);
  });
  req.on('connect',(e)=>{
   startRequest  =  new Date().getTime();
  });
  req.end();
},3000);
```

Comment: Será que essa técnica é a mais precisa possível? Dado que momento em que ele registra "o disparo da requisição" o corre antes de realmente ser disparado ?

Comment: Eu alterei a minha sugestão, tente usar o evento connect presente no httpClientRequest . Pela documentação em ( https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest ) ela serve para interceptar o início da conexão entre o cliente e o servidor, veja se funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Usa o [morganjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan), ele eh um middleware e ele faz logs de cada requisição.

Exemplo Expressjs:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan('dev')); // Essa eh uma forma de declarar um middleware "global" para todas as rotas

app.listen(3333);
```

Na linha onde tem `app.use(morgan('dev'))` esse 'dev' é o padrão do log q ele vai mostrar no console, tem varios tipos, porem ja que não se deve fazer logs em producao, so para desenvolvimento ent esse padrão('dev') serve para 90% dos casos

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');


app.get("/", morgan('dev'), (req, res) => {
    res.send("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
} // Nesse caso o morgan ira mostrar e monitorar os dados dessa rota somente, onde tem o app.get pode ser qlq metodo(app.post, app.put, app...)

app.listen(3333);
```